# How does the garbage collector work in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection

I'm working on an interactive project in JS and as a stable framerate is what I'm looking for I've decided to research a bit on how the garbage collector works in Chrome in particular. I'm not trying to manage my own memory as to avoid the GC - I just want to know how much I can abuse it and how it performs its duty.

Googling for this returns only shallow "news" articles on the lines "Chrome gets incremental garbage collector". As a result I don't know anything about it besides the fact that it's incremental.

Comment: You could probably write a book on the subject, [here is a link.](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-memory-profiling)